# In Oracle SQL developer, how can I find the number of rows in a certain table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I just wanted to know how do I can I find the number of rows in a certain table.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the tool SQL Developer. In SQL you `select count(*) from table` to get the number of rows in the table. It is weird you are asking this, as this is extremely basic. How you managed to neither find this in your SQL manual nor on the Internet is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`COUNT` aggregation function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/COUNT.html):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious `count` function, if you regularly gather schema statistics, you can - at least approximately (if tables' contents change relatively frequently) - query `user_tables` and check the `num_rows` column's contents:

```
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats('SCOTT');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select table_name, num_rows from user_tables;

TABLE_NAME             NUM_ROWS
-------------------- ----------
EMP                          14
DEPT                          4
BONUS                         0
SALGRADE                      5
INVOICE                       4
ERRORS                      110
DAT                           0
<snip>
```

Is that really so? For example:

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL> select count(*) from dept;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

SQL> select count(*) from bonus;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> select count(*) from errors;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       110

SQL>
```